# SVG Rectangle not rotating/translating group properly when using SVG transform "matrix()" function

Tags: javascript, svg, matrix, rotation

I am attempting to animate a group of SVG objects. What should be happening is the 4 coloured rectangle should move to the right, while spinning around it's center axis, but what is actually happening is a rotation around point 0,0 on the screen. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Here is the HTML/SVG

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <button id="startBtn">START/STOP</button>
    <button id="resetBtn">RESET</button>

    <svg id="thesvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1362.98 768">
        <g id="rectangle">
            <rect style="fill: red;" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
            <rect style="fill: green;" x="50" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
            <rect style="fill: yellow;" x="0" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
            <rect style="fill: blue;" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

To do this I am running the following function

```
var timer = null;
var started = false;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

// Center of rectangle
var cx=50, cy=50;
var angle = 0;

/**
* Ran every tick. Should make the rectangle move diagonally right/down 
* while spinning around it's center
*/
function running(){
  updateRectanglePosition();


    // Get the matrix of the parent element
    var rect = document.getElementById('rectangle');
    var ctm = rect.parentNode.getScreenCTM();
    var matrix = new DOMMatrix([ctm.a, ctm.b, ctm.c, ctm.d, ctm.e, ctm.f]);

    // Translate the center of the group to 0,0 of parent matrix
    matrix = matrix.translate(-(cx), -(cy));

    // Rotate around this point 
    matrix = matrix.rotate(angle % 360);

    // Translate to actual x,y position
    matrix = matrix.translate(x , y);

  rect.setAttribute('transform', matrix.inverse().toString());

  if(timer){
    timer = setTimeout(running, 100);
  }
}

// Updates rectangle position every frame
function updateRectanglePosition()
{
  x += 1;
  y += 1;
  angle = (angle + 10);
}
```

Example https://codepen.io/comfydemon/pen/jObYXYL

Answer (score 0):

The way I had to modify this was to rotate the translation vector by the opposite of the amount I rotated the shape to "undo" the coordinate system that was changed by the rotation

```
// Translate the element to the x,y pos
let translation = new DOMMatrix();
let movement = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2));
// take the x and y translation values and rotate them to the opposite of the rotation of the shape 
// toRadians just converts deg to rad
translation = translation.translate(movement * Math.cos(toRadians(360 - angle)),movement * Math.sin(toRadians(360 - angle)));
```

Answer (score -1):

The original question says that 4 rectangles are only rotating but not translating. Copying the exact code revealed that 4 boxes are infact rotating and translating as well. You are translating it by only 1 pixel after 100 ms that gave the impression that object is not moving. Try increasing pixel value and as your coordinate system is reversed, you have to use negative value for x-axis to move the object towards right.

See below Working code (Desired result):

```html
<body>


    <button id="startBtn">START/STOP</button>


    <svg id="thesvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1362.98 768">
        <g id="rectangle">
            <rect style="fill: red;" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
            <rect style="fill: green;" x="50" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
            <rect style="fill: yellow;" x="0" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
            <rect style="fill: blue;" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
        </g>

    </svg>
  
 <script>
 



var timer = null;
var started = false;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

// Center of rectangle
var cx=50, cy=50;
var angle = 0;

/**
* Ran every tick. Should make the rectangle move diagonally right/down 
* while spinning around it's center
*/

function running(){
  updateRectanglePosition();


    // Get the matrix of the parent element
    var rect = document.getElementById('rectangle');
    var ctm = rect.parentNode.getScreenCTM();
    var matrix = new DOMMatrix([ctm.a, ctm.b, ctm.c, ctm.d, ctm.e, ctm.f]);

    // Translate the center of the group to 0,0 of parent matrix
    matrix = matrix.translate(50, 50);
 
    // Rotate around this point 
    matrix = matrix.rotate(angle % 360);
 matrix = matrix.translate(x, -250);
    // Translate to actual x,y position
    //matrix = matrix.translate(x , y);

  rect.setAttribute('transform', matrix.inverse().toString());

  if(timer){
    timer = setTimeout(running, 100);
  }
}

// Updates rectangle position every frame
function updateRectanglePosition()
{
  x -= 10;
  y += 1;
  angle = (angle + 10);
}

// Starts and stops the setTimeout timer that runs the animation
function startAnimation() {
  started = !started;
  if(started){
    if(timer){
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(running, 100);
  }
  else {
    timer = clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}

// Resets the variables
function reset(){
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  angle = 0;
}

 document.getElementById('startBtn').addEventListener('click', startAnimation);

  </script>

  
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the units are backwards? Is this something I did? -10x should go left

Comment: You will have to check how the svg coordinate system and matrix works. here is detailed link [link]https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/.  Your issue in the question was that 4 squares are not translating towards middle. I solved the issue with the code snippet and still ended up in negative vote. There should be a way to dispute the -ve votes. Anyways if the code snippet I provided is moving the squares towards center while rotating then it should be accepted answer. Thanks.  Also, i'd recommend using any popular svg js library. Those makes things much simpler. cheers

Comment: But you haven't answered the question. All you did is change the sign on the units with no explanation of why. Yes I realize using a library makes things easier but I am trying to learn how things work so that doesn't help either.

Comment: I answered exactly what you had asked in original question. It was asked that objects are only rotating and not translating at all. You mentioned desired output. I answered exactly with the working code for your desired results. You had to phrase your question in the beginning with why coordinate system is reversed. But it wasn't mentioned because it was unknown at the time of question. I am glad, from answer you've figured out that objects were translating towards right by -ve x-axis which lead to 'new' question that your co-ordinate system was reversed. Glad issue is solved. Cheers.